# android google map link

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a trouble using a google map link with longitutes and latitudes that I give from an android application. The link is fine, except that when I open the link from my android device I cannot see the red spot that points the exact place. I only see the map zoomed-into that place but not the pointer itself. Do you know how I can fix this??? The url is:

```
String msgbody = "I am in: " + "https://www.google.gr/maps/@" + lat + "," + lng + ",16.5z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0";
```

Comment: This might help, use `?q=loc:` before the coordinates, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582834/use-a-url-to-link-to-a-google-map-with-a-marker-on-it/6582937#6582937

Answer (score 0):

You may use Show a location on a map

To open a map, use the `ACTION_VIEW` action and specify the location information in the intent data with one of the schemes defined below.

`geo:latitude,longitude`

Show the map at the given longitude and latitude.
Example: `"geo:47.6,-122.3"`

`geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom`

Show the map at the given longitude and latitude at a certain zoom level. A zoom level of 1 shows the whole Earth, centered at the given lat,lng. The highest (closest) zoom level is 23.
Example: `"geo:47.6,-122.3?z=11"`

For more details, please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps).

Comment: Does this helped you? If so, please accept. If not please tell me, thanks