# Dispaly the marker on Google Maps

Tags: api, maps, marker

Do you have any idea how to move the marker with the coordinates or URL? now when I click on 'Google' down on the map [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz8Ee.png) the marker disappears.
I have an example here:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8164526,-4.140963);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Compacc Complete Accountancy'
  });
  
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`

How can I show the marker on "The original Google map"?

Comment: If someone has the same issue, I found the solution thanks to 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44477650/4645162